# Saved keras model freezes kernal on inference

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

The issue I'm having is that when I load a serialized Keras LSTM model (on a separate machine, although identical config except no GPU), it loads fine, but freezes when using the `model.predict()` method.

I use the exact same method for inference after training the model (when it is still in memory), and I have no problems.

I load the model like so:

```
 def load_ner_model(self):


        mod_name_ext = '{}.h5'.format(self.mod_name)
        mod_path = 'misc/3p_ner/'

        tt_name = '{}_text_tokenizer.pickle'.format(self.mod_name)
        cc_name = '{}_char_tokenizer.pickle'.format(self.mod_name)
        lookup_name = '{}_pos_lookup.pickle'.format(self.mod_name)

        mod_files = [self.mod_name +".h5", tt_name, cc_name, lookup_name]
        for file_name in mod_files:
            if file_name not in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
                print(file_name)
                client.download_file(databuck, mod_path+ file_name, file_name)

        with open(tt_name, 'rb') as handle:
            self.text_tokenizer = pickle.load(handle)

        with open(cc_name, 'rb') as handle:
            self.char_tokenizer = pickle.load(handle)

        with open(lookup_name, 'rb') as handle:
            self.pos_lookup = pickle.load(handle)

        self.model = keras.models.load_model(mod_name_ext)
```

Then I prepare the data and make the inference like this:

```
def create_char_arrs(text):
    dummy = 'nada'
    char_arrs = list() 
    terms = text.split()
    doc_res = list()
    for term in terms[0:50]:
        res = char_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([term])
        doc_res.append(res[0])
    doc_res = sequence.pad_sequences(doc_res, maxlen=18, padding='post')
    char_arrs.append(doc_res)
    char_arrs = sequence.pad_sequences(char_arrs, maxlen=50, padding='post')
    return char_arrs

oos = text_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([x])
oos = sequence.pad_sequences(oos, maxlen=max_length, padding='post', value=36)
ch = create_char_arrs(x)
res = model.predict([ch, oos])
```

And the result is that it just freezes the kernel, no error message or anything.

I've saved and re-loaded many Keras models before and never had this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!